# How to add CircularProgressIndicator in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

Here is my all code samples. How can I add a circular progress indicator when user press the signup button?

```
    class CreateAccountScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _CreateAccountScreenState createState() => _CreateAccountScreenState();
    }
    
    class _CreateAccountScreenState extends State<CreateAccountScreen>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
    
      Future<Profile> _profile;
      ProgressDialog _progressDialog;
      bool _isloading;
```

Here is the button click Function:

```
    _pressCreateAccountButton(){
        print("User pressed \"CREATE ACCOUNT\" button");
        print("Login: ${editControllerName.text}, E-mail: ${editControllerEmail.text}, "
            "password1: ${editControllerPassword1.text}, password2: ${editControllerPassword2.text}");
        // Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/main", (r) => false);
        // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BuisnessType()));
        // MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BuisnessType());
    
    
    
        if(editControllerName.text == null || editControllerEmail.text == null || editControllerPassword1.text == null || editControllerPassword2.text == null || editControllerContact.text == null){
            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                msg: "Please input the necessary field",
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16.0);
        }else if(!editControllerEmail.text.contains("@") || !editControllerEmail.text.contains(".") || !editControllerEmail.text.contains("com")){
    
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "Please input valid email address",
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
              gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0);
        }else{
    
          _isloading = !_isloading;
    
            _profile = getProfileData(editControllerName.text.toString(), editControllerEmail.text, editControllerPassword2.text,editControllerContact.text, 3);
        }
      }
```

Here is the rest api call function:

```
Future<Profile> getProfileData(String name, String strEmail, String strPass,String strPhone, int type) async{
    await AllApiCall.userRegistration(name, strEmail, strPass, strPhone, type).then((value) {

      print(value.success.token);

      setState(() {
        _isloading = false;
      });

      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BuisnessType()));
    });
  }
```

Rest is design of that page:

```
  final editControllerName = TextEditingController();
  final editControllerEmail = TextEditingController();
  final editControllerPassword1 = TextEditingController();
  final editControllerPassword2 = TextEditingController();
  final editControllerContact = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isloading = false;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    editControllerName.dispose();
    editControllerEmail.dispose();
    editControllerPassword1.dispose();
    editControllerPassword2.dispose();
    editControllerContact.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I have added `_isloading` but its not working in my case. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `loading_overlay` package. You can find it here:
https://pub.dev/packages/loading_overlay

You will have to define a `bool isLoading`, and initially set it's value to `false`.
Like this: `bool isLoading = false;`.
Then import the `loading_overlay` package by writing
`import 'package:loading_overlay/loading_overlay.dart';` at the top of your file.

Now, wrap all of your widgets with the `LoadingOverlay` widget like this:

```
LoadingOverlay(
progressIndicator: CircularProgressIndicator(),
isLoading: isLoading, // our previously defined variable
child: YourWidgets(),
)
```

Now when you need to start a loading process you can write:
`setState(()=>isLoading=true);`
And to stop it write:`setState(()=>isLoading=false);`

If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: its working but not showing any circularprogressInditator

Comment: Try writing: `progressIndicator: CircularProgressIndicator(),` inside the `LoadingOverlay`. Like in the edit I made in the post.